# Error when upgrading from 4.7.16 to 4.7.20

Tags: upgrade

I want to upgrade my site (Drupal 7.54 to 7.55, then civicrm 4.7.16 to 4.7.20).

No problem on Drupal upgrade.

But for CiviCRM, when I run mysite/drupal/?q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1 (after having replaced sites/all/civicrm directory content) :

- upgrade to 4.7.17 runs OK
- upgrade to 4.7.18 fails with the following error :

[image]

(BTW, civicrm_case table is empty on my site)

Comment: had same issue upgrading from 4.6 to 4.7 running that SQL code in phpmyadmin fixed it. THANKS!!!! ALTER TABLE civicrm_case ADD CONSTRAINT FK_civicrm_case_case_type_id FOREIGN KEY (case_type_id) REFERENCES civicrm_case_type (id) ON DELETE SET NULL;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the foreign key mentioned in the error message doesn't exist for some reason. I would probably go into MySQL and check.  If it's not there, just create one with the same name on the `civicrm_case` table. Then try the upgrade again.

A MySQL statement to create the foreign key (from CiviCRM 4.5) is: `ADD CONSTRAINT FK_civicrm_case_case_type_id FOREIGN KEY (case_type_id) REFERENCES civicrm_case_type (id) ON DELETE SET NULL;`

Comment: Thank you Dave ; but, before I run this statement, how can I check that this foreign Key does not exist ? Actually, in my civicrm_case table, there is an UNSIGNED "case_type_id" field, commented as being "FK to civicrm_case_type.id" : isn't it already what is required ? (BTW, this table is empty)

Comment: Well, the easiest way would be to run the `add constraint` command.  If it already exists, the add will fail with some message.  No harm done.  I have no idea why the FK doesn't exist, probably a prior upgrade failed somewhere along the way.  If you want to really check for the constraint, here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004205/mysql-show-constraints-on-tables-command

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem and I had to fix it by running the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE civicrm_case
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_civicrm_case_case_type_id FOREIGN KEY (case_type_id) REFERENCES civicrm_case_type (id) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

(taken from `CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/sql/4.5.alpha1.mysql.tpl`).

Comment: I did it and it worked fine ; thank you to both of you

Answer (score -1):

had same issue upgrading from 4.6 to 4.7

running that SQL code in phpmyadmin fixed it.  THANKS!!!!

ALTER TABLE civicrm_case ADD CONSTRAINT FK_civicrm_case_case_type_id FOREIGN KEY (case_type_id) REFERENCES civicrm_case_type (id) ON DELETE SET NULL;

Comment: This is not an Answer and should be added as a Comment

Comment: Thanks for the info but I need 50 reputation before I have the ability to add a comment to other peoples answers.  I am following the guidelines since I am affirming the solution that worked for me.  your comment and downvote are not helpful to anyone.

Comment: Yep, I see that. Apologies. Trying to figure how I can convert your Answer to be a Comment only Onlyjob's Answer - then I can +1 your comment and help you get some reputation.